# Setting a theme/style when using startActivity()

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Simple question:

I am using `PICK_CONTACT` in my Android 3.0 application.
The issue is that the contact app has a light theme while my app uses a dark one.

So the question is:

Is there a way to set a style/theme when using `startActivity()`?

If I am creating my own library and I want the user to be able to use customize styles, I will need to receive something in the `intent`? Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to change the theme inside your application or inside the stock contact app? (whose theme varies depending on the phone btw)

Comment: I want to be able to pick which theme I use before starting that `Activity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a style/theme when using startActivity()?

No. You have no right to mess with other apps' user interfaces, any more than they have a right to mess with yours.

In the case of `PICK_CONTACT`, if you are willing to have the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, there is nothing stopping you from writing your own contact picker activity, themed as you wish.

> If I am creating my own library and I want the user to be able to use customize styles, I will need to receive something in the intent?

Since there is no `setStyle()` method, dynamically changing an activity's style seems troublesome.

If your library will be shipped as an Android library project, you can provide theme resources and guidance for developers who, when adding your activities to their manifest, can choose which theme to use at compile time.

Comment: Hey, I am not willing to mess with other apps' user interfaces!. I can choose a light/dark theme in the Manifest so it would make sense to set that theme on runtime.

Comment: @Macarse: But the `ACTION_PICK` for contacts is not your app. It's somebody else's app. In this case, it happens to be the operating system's app... unless the user happens to have installed a third-party contact manager, in which case it might be that app. You have no idea. If you want seamless look-and-feel integration, you have to roll your own UI. If you want convenience, link to other apps via `Intents`, but then you have to let *them* choose what the UI should look like.

Comment: @CommonsWare: ok. Feels awkward not being able to have a call to set a theme from a list of possibilities. The other thing that makes me wonder is that if I want my android app to have a set of themes and make the user decide which one to use I have to get that info from an `intent`, which sounds bad :(. Something like that should be place in the android libraries.

Comment: @Macarse: "Feels awkward not being able to have a call to set a theme from a list of possibilities." -- that would require forcing all Android developers worldwide to implement an arbitrary number of themes for all their exported activities. Do *you* want other developers forcing *you* to do extra work, not for any benefit for you, but to make *them* happy?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Wait. I didn't suggest android should force the developer. I am just willing to have the possibility to use it. Right now even if the developer **wants** to provide different themes, he can't. That's sad.

Comment: @Macarse: That's true, and it'd be a nice feature, so long as it is opt-in by the developer whose activity is being launched. Now, the problem that themes are hard-wired into the manifest comes to the foreground, so to speak. If you want to expose multiple themes, you are pretty much stuck with a bunch of `<activity-alias>` elements at best, each with a distinct `<intent-filter>`. There's more required to make this work than merely having a home for the desired theme or a convention for an extra name for the desired theme, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

No.

In general there is no standard method of specifying the theme/style an Activity should launch with: your idea (putting something in the Intent) would actually be an excellent way of doing it, but once again it isn't standard.

Wandering through the standard Contacts app source (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts
) there is no way to specify the theme in any of the Activity classes that `PICK_CONTACT` would invoke.

Your best bet would be to build a custom Contact picker and use the content provider. You'd need to ask for permissions and it would be a bit messier but that appears to be the only way to get what you want.